# Table title with kableExtra

Tags: r

I want to include a title for the table and the correct names for the columns.
How can I do it with the function kableExtra?

````
kable(tab[211:220,]) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fBG.png
````

Answer (score 14):

You can add a title using the `caption` argument and change the column names using the `col.names` argument, both of which are options when you call `kable`. This is before you even need `kableExtra`.

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(head(iris), format = "html", caption = "Title of the table", 
col.names = c("sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "species")) %>% 
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

This returns the following HTML, or shows you a HTML preview if you are using RStudio.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<caption>Title of the table</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> sepal_length </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> sepal_width </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> petal_length </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> petal_width </th>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> species </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 5.1 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.5 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 4.9 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.0 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 4.7 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.2 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.3 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 4.6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.1 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.5 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 5.0 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 5.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 3.9 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1.7 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.4 </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```