# Change the size of a title in KableExtra?

Tags: r, kableextra

I have tried many techniques (mostly around [editing the raw HTML passed to `caption`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088294/5783745) in order to change the size of a title ([aka caption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559622/5783745)) when using KableExtra.

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

Here's a simple example:

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

iris %>%
  head %>%
  kable(
    table.attr = "style = \"color: black;\"", 
    caption = "<span style='font-size:20'>A lovely title</span>"
    ) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = T)
```

But the title size doesn't change:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Span accepts CSS `font-size` in 3 different ways. Run the following examples to see them in action:

## Pixels

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)


iris %>% 
  head %>% 
  kable(
    table.attr = "style = \"color: black;\"", 
    caption = "<span style='font-size:20px'>A lovely title</span>"
    ) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = T)
```

## Percent

```r
iris %>% 
  head %>% 
  kable(
    table.attr = "style = \"color: black;\"", 
    caption = "<span style='font-size:200%'>A lovely title</span>"
    ) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = T)
```

## "small", "large" etc.

```r
iris %>% 
  head %>% 
  kable(
    table.attr = "style = \"color: black;\"", 
    caption = "<span style='font-size:small'>A lovely title</span>"
    ) %>% 
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = T)
```

[image]

- Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp)